# How can I automatically scale down to zero instances and scale up when someone does a request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running an application with multiple environments which are not always required. Ideally, *[to save some cost]* I would love to instances count to automatically decrease to zero (say an hour of inactivity), and once requests start coming scale up and start increasing instances count to serve requests.

In other words - could autoscale group or anything else within AWS EB (except API) create the first instance?

Comment: Creating EB instance takes a lot of time. You would need to sacrifice a lot of these "first" requests for being fulfilled. By the time the instance is up and running, you may have no further requests to process.